# Observing insertions and removals from NSMutableSet using observeValueForKeyPath

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I would like to be notified about a new insertion in the `NSMutableSet` and thus this is what I am doing, but for some reason it is not calling `observeValueForKeyPath` method

Just for test:

```
-(void)observ{
    [self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"connections" options:NSKeyValueChangeInsertion context:NULL];

    [connections addObject:@"connectionName"];

}
```

This is never called:

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{

    if( [keyPath isEqualToString:@"connections"] ) {

        NSLog(@"added new object");
    }
}
```

Is NSMutablSet KVC ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NSMutableSet` is indeed KVO/KVC compliant. However, in order to receive the notifications with the way you have this set up, you need to implement the KVC accessor methods for a set. Information can be found [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/AccessorConventions.html). Essentially, you have to implement methods called:

```
-countOfConnections
-enumeratorOfConnections
-memberOfConnections:
-addConnectionsObject:
-removeConnectionsObject:
-intersectConnections:
```

You must use these methods to access and mutate your set in order to receive KVO notifications.

Finally, in your `-observeValueForKeyPath` method, you can use the value of the key `kind` in the `change` dictionary to determine what type of mutation occurred (addition, deletion, etc.). The values can be found [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSKeyValueObserving_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) and are listed under "NSKeyValueChange". Hope this helps.

Comment: So, essentially the documentation says:NSMutableSet is KVO compliant.